# Transaction with highest fee, but stuck, what did I do wrong?

Tags: transactions, transaction-fees, unconfirmed-transactions, electrum

I recently sent btc that appears to be stuck (https://live.blockcypher.com/btc/tx/c131d65d933e343f852021830b833123de952c1857f264503388cf642655c457/)

The interesting thing is that I used a higher fee (4.5 sat/byte) which was the highest fee that Electrum's slider would support. I also notice that there are only two transactions in this block. Did I screw up? Is there any way that I can fix this?

Edit: Electrum says that I am only 0.12 MB from tip, however it has hovered around there without moving and sometimes increasing in size.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The hourly average fee when this question was posted was between 9 and 10 Satoshi per Byte (sat/B).

The latest TX's that I just [randomly checked](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/block/0000000000000000000e1d4ce08cb39bc27f705ea89347c8c8b4694cdcdf20bb) all had 10.03 sat/B fee which is higher than the 4.5 sat/B that you sent.

Transactions are [at a hourly peak right now](https://www.blockchain.com/en/charts/mempool-size). Wait it out and it'll probably go through in the next couple of hours as the mempool empties.

I just noticed your TX went through and has 3 confirmations from the time I started replying to now. So I guess this is a closed issue.

Comment: Since transactions can be of different size, miners actually select transactions by fee rate (fee over size), not by absolute fees.

Comment: @Murch Yep. His was 4.5 sat/B and those I checked (the first few on that block I linked to) all were 10.xx sat/B.

Comment: Block #600283 had 18 transactions with fee rates below 3 sats/B, but that's not my point. The point I was trying to make was that the absolute fee a transaction paid is not a good metric to assess its priority, because paying 2200 sats for a 1100 byte transaction is a lower fee rate than paying 1674 satoshis for a 372 byte transaction.

Comment: @Murch OK, thanks for the suggestion I've reworded the answer. Let me know please if this is better.

Answer (score 5):

Your transaction paid a fee of 1674 satoshis for 372 bytes, or a fee rate of 4.5 satoshis per byte, which was a reasonable estimate in the past hour (via https://mempool.space/tv):[image]

There was just a slow block with #600,283 taking 37 minutes to be found (via https://blockchair.com) and it looks like your transaction would have been exactly in that little blue corner above the dotted line.

[image]

Otherwise, four of the last six blocks were not even full, so if not for that slower block, it would have been included in the next block (via https://mempool.space/tv):
[image: overview of last six blocks]

Should you do get a transaction stuck during a congestion phase sometime in the future, check out this canonical question: [Why is my transaction not getting confirmed and what can I do about it?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/9046/5406)